# Getting over lapping guitar sound

Tags: guitar, recording, microphones, pre-amp

I am recording semi-acoustic guitar and vocals at same time in reaper through scarlett 2i2(2nd gen)

- Input 1 --guitar
- Input 2 --mic

but my mic catches guitar sound too and when I listen to my recording the guitar and vocals overlap. Is there any solution so that I record only vocals through mic without having guitar sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real easy way to achieve this. The two are so close together that total separation is just not possible.

Historically it comes down to two choices...

1. Record each separately
2. Live with it.

You can get a slight improvement by using more directional microphones, or by trying to place an absorber between your face & body [uncomfortable & you can't see what you're playing].

After comments, there's a 3rd option.
 3. Use a quieter guitar with pickups. I actually used to do this sometimes with a Line6 Variax set to an acoustic guitar sound - reasonably successfully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50436/discussion-between-dr-mayhem-and-tetsujin).

Comment: Does sound hole cover help to decrease the guitar sound

Comment: Yes, but it will make it sound terrible.

Comment: Is there any other way :(